# H.264 AVC supported for android phones?

Tags: android

I am totally confused after reading 2 different posts today. With the research I did in android docs, I learnt H.264 AVC is not supported for versions lower than Android OS 3.0 according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) and at the same time I come across [this](http://androidforums.com/android-lounge/36571-android-phones-supporting-h-264-video-streaming.html) forum post saying it is supported. please give me a definite answer. I am trying to show live stream of an IPCamera in my app through rtsp URL which my client is sending. It is in H.264 AVC media codec format

Comment: He has said about the phone since OEM can support the format but Android only supports above 3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia says: "Google's Android platform for mobile devices natively supports H.264 (based on PacketVideo's OpenCORE) On the T-Mobile G1, a Qualcomm MSM7200 CPU provides hardware decoding." [HERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.264/MPEG-4_AVC_products_and_implementations)

H.264 is a standard, then, I think it will work. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5869522/android-mpeg4-h-264-packetization-example) topic could help you.

Comment: The android docs say H.264 baseline profile, • MPEG-TS (.ts, AAC audio only, not seekable, Android 3.0+).....what does this mean?

Comment: The project target must be android >3.0

Comment: I am actually looking for sources where I can live stream an rtsp url in my android phone. The client is sending me rtsp url and I can view it in VLC player but not able to view it in phones since my phone has froyo. I want to know if H.264 is the reason I am not able to see the live stream or not.